# Godot 4 Dictionary issues with PhysicasRayQueryParameters2D C#

Tags: c#, raycasting, variant, godot4

Following [this](https://youtu.be/6k_MyPwwygE?si=N4w_rBNholVAhQQw&t=1284) tutorial (its a bit back in Godot 3) and I have run into some issues with `PhysicasRayQueryParameters2D`. Here is the code from the video:

```
if (ableToShoot)
{
    var spaceState = GetWorld2D().DirectSpaceState;
    Godot.Collections.Dictionary result = spaceState.IntersectRay(this.Position, player.Position, new Godot.Collections.Array {this} );

    if (result != null)
    {
        if (result.Contains("collider"))
        {
            if (result["collider"] == player)
            {
                GD.Print("Shooting");
                ableToShoot = false;
                shootTimer = shootTimerReset;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my code:

```
if (ableToShoot)
{
    var spaceState = GetWorld2D().DirectSpaceState;
    //Change 1
    var query = PhysicsRayQueryParameters2D.Create(this.Position, player.Position);
    query.Exclude = new Godot.Collections.Array<Rid> {  };
    query.CollisionMask = 1;
    Godot.Collections.Dictionary result = spaceState.IntersectRay(query);

    if (result != null)
    {
        if (result.ContainsKey("collider")) //Change 2
        {
            if (result["collider"] == player) //Error Message
            {
                GD.Print("Shooting");
                ableToShoot = false;
                shootTimer = shootTimerReset;
            }
        }
    }
```

The code from the video is obviously different due to the changes form Godot 3 to 4. However, I am not entirely sure if the corrections/changes I have made are the correct ones. I am still new to both C# and Godot. I marked the two places I made changes so that it is easier to compare. My main issue however is that I keep getting an error message where it says `result["collider"] == player`.
That is how it was in the tutorial, and I did it myself but I get an error when I do, saying that I cannot use the '==' opperators when applyed to a `Variant` and `PlayerController`(a class from a different script). I tried casting result into a `PlayerController`, but once the tile's started blocking between me and the enemy I started getting error messages saying that I cannot convert `Godot.TileMap` to `Godot.PlayerController`. What should I do instead? And are there any other mistakes I have made when translating the code?

I looked over many reddit forms and the Godot documentation but I could not get over that last error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Godot.Variant` is a struct that can hold one of many types of values, including native C# types (strings, integers, arrays of basic types, etc) and a collection of internal Godot types. While there are a bunch of different implicit type conversions (i.e. the compiler tries to figure out what type you need and calls the appropriate type conversion method on `Variant`), you often need to explicitly extract something from a `Variant` before you can work with it.

(The full list of types you can find in a `Variant` is [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_variant.html#variant-compatible-types).)

In this case, the `collider` value from `IntersectRay`'s result dictionary is a `GodotObject` which you can do equality comparisons on... once C# knows what type it is.

There are a couple of ways to go about this using conversion operators, the `As*()` methods such as `AsObject()` and so on. Here are a couple of options that might work for you:

**`Variant.AsObject()`:**

```
if (result["collider"].AsObject() == player)
{
}
```

**Explicit cast:**

```
if ((GodotObject)result["collider"] == player)
{
}
```

**Implicit cast to variable:**

```
GodotObject? collider = results["collilder"];
if (collider == player)
{
}
```

And finally, there's the `Obj` member which will fetch the internal value as a c# `object?` which you can do reference comparisons on.

**`Obj` reference comparision:**

```
if (ReferenceEquals(results["collider"].Obj, player))
{
}
```

This isn't an exhaustive list, but hopefully one of those will work for you. Using `ReferenceEquals()` works in most cases and bypasses any operator overloaing of equality for situations where you really don't need anything other than a reference compare, which is both faster and (all too often) more immediately understandable.